# VB.NET ODBC connection to DB2

Tags: vb.net, db2, odbc

Trying to migrate the database for a program from **Microsoft Access** to **DB2**.  Have the tables setup, data migrated.  Now I'm trying to update our program to read the data from **DB2**...

Well, I can't get it to connect via my program.  I'm able to connect to it via the Tools > Connect to Database in Visual Studio (screenshot below).  I'm also showing the database available via my **System DSN listings** for the datasource (**DB2DEVL** in this case; connections for both 32-bit and 64-bit).

Alas, I still get:

```
{"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}
```

Any insight into why or how I resolve this would be appreciated.

```
db2Con As New OdbcConnection
db2da As New OdbcDataAdapter
db2cmd As New OdbcCommand

db2Con.ConnectionString = "DSN=DB2DEVL,uid=XXXXXXX;psw=XXXXXX;"

strSQL = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM OL.TOL_USER_DATA WHERE N_EMPL = '" & UCase(userID) & "' or X_EMPL_DOMAIN like '" & LCase(userID) & "'"

db2da = New OdbcDataAdapter(strSQL, db2Con.ConnectionString)
db2Con.Open()
db2cmd = New OdbcCommand(strSQL, db2Con)
mainCount = CInt(db2cmd.ExecuteScalar)
```

> [DB2DEVL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VOqS.png)
>
> [ODBC Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2HrA.png)

Comment: One issue is the comma before `uid`.  It should be a semi-colon.  Also, [here is a link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2-odbc/) to DB2 connection strings.  It might be helpful.

Comment: Yep, that was it...  Thanks for catching my stupid syntax mistake!